# How can I play audio clip when moving a slider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

As in my other question I'm using one audio mixer with two groups for the game scene and the main menu scene.

In the main menu scene I have audio source for the music and audio source for the sfx effects.
When the game start in the main menu the music is playing automatic on the awake.,

The sfx is not playing and I want that when I change the sfx slider it will sound the sfx effect for a short time so each time I change the slider value it will play the sfx to hear the volume of it.

[Audio settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmP6j.jpg)

The sliders as they look like in the game :

[sliders in game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHmJZ.jpg)

The settings script when I set also the audio volumes :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using System;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System.Linq;

public class Settings : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;
    public TMP_Dropdown resolutionDropdown;
    public TMP_Dropdown qualityDropdown;
    public Text musicText;
    public Text sfxText;
    public Slider[] audioSliders;
    public Toggle fullScreenToggle;

    private Resolution[] resolutions;

    private void Awake()
    {
        resolutionDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(new UnityAction<int>(index =>
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("resolutionvalue", resolutionDropdown.value);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

        }));

        qualityDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(new UnityAction<int>(index =>
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("qualityvalue", qualityDropdown.value);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

        }));

        fullScreenToggle.onValueChanged.AddListener(new UnityAction<bool>(index =>
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("fullscreen", boolToInt(fullScreenToggle.isOn));
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

        }));
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        qualityDropdown.value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("qualityvalue");

        var resolutions = Screen.resolutions.Where(resolution => resolution.refreshRate == 60).ToArray();
        resolutionDropdown.ClearOptions();

        List<string> options = new List<string>();

        int currentResolutionIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++)
        {
            string option = resolutions[i].width + " x " + resolutions[i].height;
            options.Add(option);

            if(resolutions[i].width == Screen.currentResolution.width &&
                resolutions[i].height == Screen.currentResolution.height)
            {
                currentResolutionIndex = i;
            }
        }

        resolutionDropdown.AddOptions(options);
        resolutionDropdown.value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("resolutionvalue", currentResolutionIndex);
        resolutionDropdown.RefreshShownValue();

        float musicvolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("musicvolume");
        float sfxvolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("sfxvolume");

        musicText.text = musicvolume.ToString();
        sfxText.text = sfxvolume.ToString();
        audioSliders[0].value = musicvolume / 100f;
        audioSliders[1].value = sfxvolume / 100f;

        fullScreenToggle.isOn = intToBool(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("fullscreen", 0));
        
    }

    public void SetResolution(int resolutionIndex)
    {
        if (resolutions != null)
        {
            Resolution resolution = resolutions[resolutionIndex];
            Screen.SetResolution(resolution.width, resolution.height, Screen.fullScreen);
        }
    }

    public void SetMusicVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("musicvol", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        musicText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("musicvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    }

    public void SetSfxVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("sfxvol", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        sfxText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("sfxvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    }

    public void SetQuality(int qualityIndex)
    {
        QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex);
    }

    public void SetFullscreen(bool isFullscreen)
    {
        Screen.fullScreen = isFullscreen;        
    }

    int boolToInt(bool val)
    {
        if (val)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    bool intToBool(int val)
    {
        if (val != 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Maybe my whole logic is wrong, but I want to give the player the option to change the music and sfx volumes to decide what will be loader and what less.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could do it like e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private AudioSource SfxSource;

public void SetSfxVolume(float volume)
{
    audioMixer.SetFloat("sfxvol", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
    sfxText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("sfxvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));

    if(!SfxSource.isPlaying) SfxSource.Play();
}
```

Or use [`AudioSource.PlayOneShot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html).

Comment: I used a breakpoint on this line : if (!SfxSource.isPlaying) and it's all the time true when moving the slider of the sfx volume.  It's never false.

Comment: I managed to make it working. Because two audio sources are on the same gameobject I changed the script a bit.  At the top instead single audiosource I did array : [SerializeField] private AudioSource[] audioSources; then in the function of the sfx : if (!audioSources[1].isPlaying)
            audioSources[1].Play();

Comment: Now I'm facing another problem. If I'm moving the slider too fast it will start playing over again the sfx when I stop the slider. So if I'm in value 7 and moved fast the slider to 23 it will play it again on value 23. but I want it to be played on each value of the slider when moving the slider slow or fast. Any ideas how to solve it ?

Comment: in this case you could skip the check and just use `SfxSource.Play();`